# Something seems badly wrong with RPG.SE's and RPG.META.SE's CSS

Tags: bug, css

I suspect something is deeply out of whack with RPG.SE's CSS (also for the RPG.META.SE site). I am not getting this on other SE sites currently (notice the between-text spacing, and the inconsistent font rendering in the second pic):

[image: Janky-ass text formatting on RPG.SE]

[image: More janky-ass text formatting on RPG.SE]

Also: on RPG.META,SE:

[image: Janky-ass text formatting on RPG.META.SE also.]

But not on other SE sites (SCIFI.SE for comparison, none of the others in the SE network I have checked have this problem):

[image: Not-janky-ass text formatting.]

Is this a bug?

**Update 1:** I am using Firefox on Ubuntu 22.04.

**Update 2:** I get this behavior with all extensions disabled (and without them disabled). I *am not* running Firefox in 'private mode'.

**Update 3:** I also get the behavior when `extensions.webextensions.userScripts.enabled` is explicitly set to `false` in about:config.

Comment: Do you have any user scripts running?

Comment: (No repro in iOS Safari and Chrome desktop).

Comment: I typically use Stylus for font control (applies to all SE sites), but I disabled and still get the behavior.

Comment: And you’re sure you have all userscripts turned off?

Comment: @ThomasMarkovisonStrike Yes. I get the same behavior in Firefox when restarted in troubleshooting mode (all extensions disabled).

Comment: @ThomasMarkovisonStrike I also get the behavior when `extensions.webextensions.userScripts.enabled` is explicitly set to `false` in about:config.

Comment: Potentially relevant MSE post: [We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364048/335251) – has anything changed on your system that has caused this to change recently on your end?

Comment: @V2Blast In May 2021 I adopted [Stylus](https://add0n.com/stylus.html) because the system font on Ubuntu made the pages difficult for me to read. This has proved a great help. However, as of somewhere around the start of this month, the display issues I presented above emerged (maybe a bit earlier?) Stylus does not resolve them (which, as noted, persist when I disable Stylus and all other extensions). Because this behavior only appears on RPG.SE and RPG.META.SE, but not on my other SE sites, I assume this is a site-specific problem (that assumption might prove false).